# many-to-many query mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, many-to-many

I have 3 tables:
**users**

```
+-----+--------+
| id  |  name  |
+-----+--------+
|  1  |  John  |
+-----+--------+
|  2  |  Mike  |
+-----+--------+
```

**files**

```
+-----+--------+
|  id |  file  |
+-----+--------+
|  22 | file1  |
+-----+--------+
|  23 | file2  |
+-----+--------+
```

and table relationship **usersfiles**

```
+-------+--------+
| usrID | fileID |
+-------+--------+
|   1   |   22   |
+-------+--------+
|   2   |   22   |
+-------+--------+
|   2   |   23   |
+-------+--------+
```

How should the mysql query for this question look like?

Select all files enabled for current user.
Answer for this example would look like this:
for user `John` enabled just `file1`. For user `Mike` enabled files `file1` and `file2`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this

```
SELECT name, file FROM users,userfiles, files WHERE users.id = userfiles.usrid AND usersfiles.fileid = files.id;
```

Comment: In answer I need just 2 columns from table `files`

Comment: ok I need just columns from ONE table `files`. How change this sql question?

Comment: replace * with that columns name you want

Answer (score 2):

That is a simple join:

```
select files.id from users join usersfile on users.id=usrid join files on fileID=files.id where userid= <userid>
```

Comment: @SergeiMaslovskiy Have changed my anser. hope that is what you need.

Comment: It's look great, tnx. But how can I put just fields from one table `files` in result?

Comment: @SergeiMaslovskiy Sorry can't get you. Give me an example of expected result please.

Comment: example result in this case would looks like: for user John answer: `22 file1`; for Mike: `22 file1; 23 file2`

Comment: @SergeiMaslovskiy Have changed my answer. Please check.

Comment: @SergeiMaslovskiy What is the problem now?

Comment: In your answer selected columns from `files` table, but you write `from users`?

Comment: this code works: `SELECT files.id FROM users,usersfiles, files WHERE users.id = usersfiles.user AND usersfiles.file = files.id AND users.id = 2;`

Comment: how it rewrite using join?